# checking if at least one radio button has been selected - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Supposed I had the following `HTML` form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Choose</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <h1>Choose</h1>

    <p><input type="radio" name="choose" value="psychology"><font size="5" color="#0033CC">Instant Psychology</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="geography"><font size="5" color="#CC0000">Instant Geography</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="gastronomy"><font size="5" color="#660033">Instant Gastronomy</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go"></p>
  </form>


</body><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css,"></html>
```

How can I write a `JavaScript` function to make sure at least one radio input has been selected?

Comment: I think you want checkboxes not radios...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looping over the `<input>` tags, check the type and if it is checked.

```
function isOneChecked() {
  // All <input> tags...
  var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0; i<chx.length; i++) {
    // If you have more than one radio group, also check the name attribute
    // for the one you want as in && chx[i].name == 'choose'
    // Return true from the function on first match of a checked item
    if (chx[i].type == 'radio' && chx[i].checked) {
      return true;
    } 
  }
  // End of the loop, return false
  return false;
}
```

[Here it is in action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AQk8/)

Answer (score 45):

Something like this should do the trick

```
if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").length > 0) {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

**UPDATE**
Did not see that it's not supposed to have jQuery, so here's an alternative function to check that in pure JS

```
 function check(){
     var radios = document.getElementsByName("choice");

     for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (radios[i].checked) {
              return true;
          }
     }

     return false;
 }
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag on this question.

Comment: Ops, did not see that. Sorry =/

Answer (score 14):

This is possible to do without javascript if your targeted browsers support the [HTML5 required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="choose" value="psychology" required>
<input type="radio" name="choose" value="geography" required>
<input type="radio" name="choose" value="gastronomy" required>
```

Note that in chrome you only need to put `required` on one of the inputs.  I am not sure what other browsers do.

I usually do this in addition to a javascript validation (like the selected answers) so that html 4 browsers are supported as well.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it this way.

```
if(document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked') == null) {
    window.alert("You need to choose an option!");
}
```

Comment: document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]:checked')

Comment: This didn't work for me, if neither inputs were selected then it showed the error correctly, but then when I selected one the error still displayed, assume that's because there is still 1 input unselected?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you needed to know if 'at least one input is selected', you probably want checkboxes rather than radio buttons. (You can only select one radio button at a time from a group of radio buttons that share a `name` value.)

You should probably drop the `font` tags and update your HTML a little bit too:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Choose</h1>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckb-psychology" name="choose" value="psychology">
    <label for="ckb-psychology" class="blue">Instant Psychology</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckb-geography" name="choose" value="geography">
    <label for="ckb-geography" class="red">Instant Geography</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckb-gastronomy" name="choose" value="gastronomy">
    <label for="ckb-gastronomy" class="purple">Instant Gastronomy</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go">
```

**CSS**

```
label { font-size: 1.5em; }

.blue { color: #0033CC; }
.red { color: #CC0000; }
.purple { color: #660033; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function isOneChecked ( name ) {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName( name ),
        i = checkboxes.length - 1;

    for ( ; i > -1 ; i-- ) {

        if ( checkboxes[i].checked ) { return true; }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is asked for a `JS` solution. However, here's a very simple trick to get this done using `HTML`. You can simply use the `required` keyword in the `HTML input tag`.

**Sample code**

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
```

**Your form**

Please note that you only need to mention the `required` keyword once for the entire radio-group.

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <h1>Choose</h1>

    <p><input type="radio" name="choose" value="psychology" required><font size="5" color="#0033CC">Instant Psychology</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="geography"><font size="5" color="#CC0000">Instant Geography</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choose" value="gastronomy"><font size="5" color="#660033">Instant Gastronomy</font><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go"></p>
  </form>
```