# If statement to validate if a radio button selection is made

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get a piece of validation code working. On my HTML page I have a radio button group (5 buttons with values of 1-5). On the submit button being clicked I need an IF statement in Javascript to check if a selection has been made in 1 of the 5 radio buttons in the group. How would I accomplish this? The code I wrote to make the radio buttons is:

```
// Technical knowledge rating
    oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        id : 'L-Tech',
        text : '1. Technical Knowledge' });
    var oRBG = new sap.ui.commons.RadioButtonGroup({
        id : 'RBG-Tech',
        tooltip : 'Rate the intern for Technical Knowledge (1 = Unsatisfied, 5 = Outstanding)',
        columns : 5,
        editable : true });
    var oItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
        id : 'RB-Rate1',
        text : '1',
        tooltip : 'Unsatisfactory',
        key : '1' });
    oRBG.addItem(oItem);
    var oItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
        id : 'RB-Rate2',
        text : '2',
        tooltip : 'Improvement Needed',
        key : '2' });
    oRBG.addItem(oItem);
    var oItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
        id : 'RB-Rate3',
        text : '3',
        tooltip : 'Meets Expectations',
        key : '3' });
    oRBG.addItem(oItem);
    var oItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
        id : 'RB-Rate4',
        text : '4',
        tooltip : 'Exceeds Expectations',
        key : '4' });
    oRBG.addItem(oItem);
    oItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
        id : 'RB-Rate5',
        text : '5',
        tooltip : 'Outstanding',
        key : '5' });
    oRBG.addItem(oItem);
    oMatrix.createRow(oLabel, oRBG);        
    oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
        id : 'L-Text',
        text : 'Notes (Optional):', 
        design : sap.ui.commons.TextViewDesign.L3   });
    oCell = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell({
        colSpan : 4 });
    oTA = new sap.ui.commons.TextArea({
        id : 'TA-Text',
        tooltip : 'Remarks',
        editable : true,
        wrapping : sap.ui.core.Wrapping.Off,
        width : '200px',
        height : '60px'
        });
    oLabel.setLabelFor(oTA);
    oCell.addContent(oTA);
    oMatrix.createRow(oLabel, oCell);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking if at least one radio button has been selected - JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060313/checking-if-at-least-one-radio-button-has-been-selected-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(document.getElementById('id_of_button1').checked) {
  // radio button1 is checked
}else if(document.getElementById('id_of_button2').checked) {
  // radio button2 is checked
}
else if(document.getElementById('id_of_button3').checked) {
  // radio button3 is checked
}
else if(document.getElementById('id_of_button4').checked) {
  // radio button4 is checked
}
else if(document.getElementById('id_of_button5').checked) {
  // radio button5 is checked
}
```