# How to control if a radio button is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have 3 radio group and 6 radio buttons. During the form's submit event user should check at least one radio from different radio groups otherwise the submit event returns false but when i try to do this by using below implementation it always return false so i'am not able to post this form now. What can be the problem ?

HTML

```
<form id="internshipStage2Form" method="POST" action="form2.php">
    <table id="companyInformation" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                <label id="" for="">Did the engineering students work as trainees in the company in the previous years?</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                Yes<input class="radioInput" id="g1Positive" type="radio" name="g1" value="YES"/>
                No<input class="radioInput" id="g1Negative" type="radio" name="g1" value="NO"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                <label>Are the company owners and the top managers are your relatives ?</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                Yes<input class="radioInput" id="g2Positive" type="radio" name="g2" value="YES"/>
                No<input class="radioInput" id="g2Negative" type="radio" name="g2" value="NO"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                <label>Is the firm you declared above on this form same with the firm you intern firstly?</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">
                Yes<input class="radioInput" id="g3Positive" type="radio" name="g3" value="YES"/>
                No<input class="radioInput" id="g3Negative" type="radio" name="g3" value="NO"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input id="sendButton" type="submit" name="sendButton2" value="SEND FOR APPROVEMENT"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#internshipStage2Form').submit(function(){  
       var reqRadioFlag = 1;

       $('input:radio').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
              reqRadioFlag = 0;
              return false;
            } 
        });

        if(reqRadioFlag === 0){
           alert("Please fill all requiredd areas !");
           return false;
       }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060313/checking-if-at-least-one-radio-button-has-been-selected-javascript - same question

Comment: This is not same question. I have 3 different radio groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#internshipStage2Form').submit(function(event){  
    if($('input:radio:checked').length < 3)
    {
        alert("Please fill all requiredd areas !");
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFaP2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if every group is checked:

```
if ($('input[name=g1]:checked').length && $('input[name=g2]:checked').length && $('input[name=g3]:checked').length) //do submit
```

or check if there are 3 radio checked

```
if ($('input:checked').length == 3) //do submit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('table#companyInformation tr').each(function(){
     var elem =$(this).children("td").eq(1);
     if(!elem.find("input:radio:checked").length){
       reqRadioFlag = 0;
       return false;
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mvadu/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Hiral deleted their answer, considering it's the most correct.

```
<input type="radio" required />
```

So long as just one of the radio buttons in the set has this attribute, the user will be required to select *any one* of the radio button set. It's a little weird, but I can promise you it works.

HTML5 validation is far more reliable than jQuery because it doesn't rely on you at all. We make mistakes in code and that breaks things, but with `required` it doesn't matter. It will even work if the user disables JavaScript ;)

Of course, as always, be sure to validate server-side!