# quick html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p> 1. </p></td>
                        <td><label> I am cool </label></td>
                        <div class="allQuestion">
                        <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> </td> <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
</table><!-- strength_table end -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br/>
</form>
```

js

```
function validateForm(){
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("allQuestion");
  for( var j=0; j<questions.length; j++){
    if( !isOneInputChecked(questions[j], "radio")){
      formValid = false;
    }
  }
  alert(formValid ? "Submisson succesful!" : "Submisson Failed");
  return formValid;
}



function isOneInputChecked(sel){
  var inputs = sel.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for(var k = 0; k < inputs.length; k++){
    if(inputs[k].checked)
      return true;
  };
    return false;
};
```

i am using this to validate my radio question , it work perfectly but once i put the `<td>` before `<input>` , it work weird , i know it target the all input warp by allQuestion and td is blocking it.

any idea how i keep the td in place and make the script works ?
i tryed this code but didt work

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("allQuestion").getElementsByTag("Td");
```

Comment: Don't store a div inside a table, and don't store a td in a div. That makes no sense. Just give the td's your making class Question and loop through it with a foreach loop or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using **table elements** as a layout. I know it seems convenient when you first start off, but save yourself the trouble and just go straight into learning to style with **css**

```
function validateForm(){
  var checked = document.querySelector('form').elements.some(function(el){
    return el.checked;
  });
  if(checked){
    //at least one is checked
  } else {
    //none are checked
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i do , so i just remove the table ? and style with css with all my radio ?

Comment: yes add classes to them and then style them in css using class selector or **input[type="radio"]** that can be your selector

Comment: Your very welcome the best thing you'll end up learning is about flexbox:
http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

even though you should learn that later on **bookmark it** that will help you get things aligned like you want with the table layout

Comment: I realized you commented on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507437/loop-through-and-validate-multiple-radio-inputs

I also answered that one at the bottom

Comment: one simple question , if i remove table and td , so i replace all with div and input ?

Comment: it all depends on exactly what you're trying to do, but you may. Just keep at it and eventually you'll know what you want to do.

If you need more help, just comment again here but I'm about to go to sleep

Answer (score 0):

1. I didn't exactly test this,  but just try to give an id to the td that u are targeted. 
   var questions = document.getElementsByTag("id_name"); //id_name is the id of the td

*just extra notes, using table is not a good practice, use other simple HTML and CSS for more flexibilty and readble code.