# Validation with input[type="radio"] return always false

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have an `input[type="radio"]`, with no checked option by default, and i need to return false if none of these options are checked.

I'm exploring javascript only, so a jquery, angular or any other will be useles (at this moment).
I'm able to iterate over a `radioObj` and select its value, but i can't return false if no option is checked (actually, i can't return true)

not exactly what i have, but...

```
<input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radioGrp">opt1
<br>
<input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radioGrp">opt2
```

and in JS i have...

```
var rdObj = document.getElementByName("radioGrp");
var selectedValue;

for (var i = 0, length = rdObj.length; i < length; i++){
if(!rdObj[i].checked){
        alert("Select one option");
        return false;
    }else{
        //do something with value of radio checked value
    }
}
```

This code always gives me the `alert("Select one option")`, no matter if i select one option or not.
Need for validation.

Any hel will be very appreciated

Comment: This code will just run once when the page loads, you have to execute it on change of input too. Also `getElementByName` should be `getElementsByName`, and remove the `return` inside the loop.

Comment: testing right now...

Comment: Note that your alert will fire twice in the case both elements are unchecked. Instead, set a flag outside the for loop and update it within.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking if at least one radio button has been selected - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060313/checking-if-at-least-one-radio-button-has-been-selected-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonke, i've tried the solution in there, but gives me the same problem, always returns false

Comment: @HereticMonkey needed a flag outside.
Thanks for the advise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radioGrp");
  var formValid = false;

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      formValid = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!formValid) {
    alert("Select one option");
  }

  return formValid;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    
    <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radioGrp">opt1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radioGrp">opt2
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need.
Thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to wait for an event before you do any sort of value checking, otherwise your script will only run once, and at this point in time, nothing would have ever had the chance be checked.

You can attach a [change event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) to each of your radios...

```js
var myRadios = document.querySelectorAll('[name=radioGrp]');
var selectedValue;

myRadios.forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
})

function changeHandler(evt) {
  // do some check in here
  console.log(evt.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radioGrp" value='opt1'>opt1
<br>
<input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radioGrp" value='opt2'>opt2
```

...or you can attach a [submit event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) to your form and do some checking of your data then.

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('form');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', submitHandler);

function submitHandler(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(evt.target);
  const optionVal = data.get('radioGrp');
  // do some check in here
  if (!optionVal) {
    console.log(`Please select a value`)
  } else {
    console.log(`Thanks for selecting ${optionVal}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radioGrp" value='opt1'>opt1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radioGrp" value='opt2'>opt2
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Don't know if my form has some problems, but this don't work.
i'll get into the events, not very awared of that.
thanks :)

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Now this works very well, but I do not have much experience with events, but this will undoubtedly help me get into them.
I will give a lot of thought to this this week.
Thank you