# How to make requiered for a specific button a set of HTML radios?

Tags: html, css

For example, given these radios:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="1_1" required="">True</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="1_1" required="">False</input>
```

and this button (continue to the next page button):

```
<button type="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"> <b>Click here for going to the next page</b></button>
```

How can I force the user to select at least one radio, before pressing the button? That is, if the user do not select any of the radios, a legend appears saying he needs to answer at least one option? I tried to set the type of the button like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="1_1" required="button">True</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="1_1" required="button">False</input>
```

And include this script:

```
  function check(){
      var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");

      for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
           if (radios[i].checked) {
               return true;
           }
      }

      return false;
  }
```

However, both attempts are not working. Any idea about how to force the user to answer before pressing the continue button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking if at least one radio button has been selected - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060313/checking-if-at-least-one-radio-button-has-been-selected-javascript)

Comment: What made you think `required="button"` would make any sense to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I do not know, I just want to make reference to that particular button. I have more and I want the user comple all the radios before clicking that particular button.

Comment: Maybe you can have the button disabled?

Comment: @DespinaKastani I am using the radios and button as in the question

Comment: […] Well then the validation does not get triggered either, you would have to do that yourself then - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7002230/1427878 (But that would trigger validation of the whole form, so if you are trying to get some sort of tabbed form set up here, this will still require additional work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a few lines of javascript

```html
<input type="radio" value="1" name="1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">True</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="1_1" required onclick="enableButton()">False</input>


<p><i>Please select an option to go to the next page</i></p>


<button type="button" id="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" disabled onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"><b>Click here for going to the next page</b></button>

<script>
  function enableButton(target) {
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="1_1"]:checked') !== null) {
      document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, one last thing, if I have 10 buttons and all of them are different, how should I adjust `querySelector` to cover all those cases?

Comment: @anon, You can solve the 10-button issue by duplicating the script and using other radio-group `name` and button `id`.
The best thing would be to have a single script written in a more elegant way, but you need to see your code to understand how the radio+button blocks are divided.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<form id="testForm" onsubmit="return show('Page2','Page1');"> 
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="1_1" required>True</input>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="1_1" required>False</input>

  <button type="submit" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto"> <b>Click here for going to the next page</b></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the issue now is that my radios are between div tags, how can I force the form in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried what you are asking? It shouldn't matter as long as they are wrapped in a form. If for any reason this doesn't work (it should) you can always explicitly add the form attribute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in a form ,make `button` type `submit` and replace the `onclick` by `onsubmit`:

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="1_1" required>True</input>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="1_1" required>False</input>
<button type="submit" onsubmit="return show('Page2','Page1');" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto"> <b>Click here for going to the next page</b></button>
</form>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit) to stop refreshing on submit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I guess this is not working because all my elements are wrapped inside a div, any idea of how to include them into the form?

Comment: @anon You can put the div inside the form

Comment: This is how it looks: `<form><div id="Page1" onsubmit="return show('Page2','Page1');>... the radios and the button ...</div></form>` Here the problem is that I get redirected to the next page, instead of stopping me and ask for complete the radios

Comment: divs don't accept an `onsubmit` attribute. This should remain in the form