# At least one radio and checkbox must be select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

`how to validate all the section by at least choose one option`. with my code, it just show the first "please select 1". so how to edit the code to show the `all requirement` like "pls choose at least one" `at beside the section or below the submit button`. I'm just a beginner, now learning for JavaScript. You are prefer to done with some code editor, to have a better understand for beginner. Here is my code :

```js
var person = [];
person["person1"]=1; 
person["person2"]=2;
person["person3"]=3;
person["person4"]=4;
person["person5"]=5;

var elec = [];
elec["elecuse"] = 0;
elec["elec1"] = 100*454.58;
elec["elec2"] = 200*454.58;
elec["elec3"] = 300*454.58;
elec["elec4"] = 400*454.58;
elec["elec5"] = 500*454.58;
elec["elec6"] = 600*454.58;
elec["elec7"] = 700*454.58;
elec["elec8"] = 800*454.58;
elec["elec9"] = 900*454.58;

function getNumberperson()
{  
    var numberperson=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedPerson[i].checked)
        {
            numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
        }
    }
    return numberperson;
}

function getElectotal()
{
    var electotal=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var selectedElec = theForm.elements["electricity"];     
    electotal = elec[selectedElec.value];
    return electotal;
}

function recyclealu()
{
    var recyclealu=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var yesalu = theForm.elements["yesalu"];

    if(yesalu.checked==true)
    {
        recyclealu=-89.38;
    }
    return recyclealu;
}

function recycleplas()
{
    var recycleplas=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var yesplas = theForm.elements["yesplas"];

    if(yesplas.checked==true)
    {
        recycleplas=-35.56;
    }
    return recycleplas;
}
 
function checkAllRecycles() {
    const recycleBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  if (recycleBoxes) {
    recycleBoxes.forEach((recycleBox) => {
      if (!recycleBox.checked) {
        recycleBox.checked = 'checked';
      }
    })
  }
  calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalco = getNumberperson()*getElectotal() + recyclealu() + recycleplas();
    
    //display the result

    document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = +totalco;

}

//add a function to hide the result on page loading at the start
function hideTotal()
{
    document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = "0";
} 

function vpeople()
{
    var cp = document.getElementsByName('selectedperson');
    for (var i = 0; i < cp.length; i++)
    {
       if (cp[i].type == 'radio')
        {
        if (cp[i].checked) {return true}
        }
    }
  return false;
}

function velec()
{
    var ce = document.getElementsByName('electricity');
    for (var i = 0; i < ce.length; i++)
    {
       if (ce[i].type == 'radio')
        {
        if (ce[i].checked) {return true}
        }
    }
  return false;
}

function vrcyalu()
{
    var crcyalu = document.getElementsByName('yesalu');
    for (var i = 0; i < crcyalu.length; i++)
    {
       if (crcyalu[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
        if (crcyalu[i].checked) {return true}
        }
    }
  return false;
}

function vrcyplas()
{
    var crcyplas = document.getElementsByName('yesalu');
    for (var i = 0; i < crcyplas.length; i++)
    {
       if (crcyplas[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
        if (crcyplas[i].checked) {return true}
        }
    }
  return false;
}

function allvalidate()
{
    if(!vpeople())
    {
        alert("Please select1");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    if(!vwaste())
    {
        alert("Please select2");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    if(!velec())
    {
        alert("Please select3");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    if(!vrcyalu())
    {
        alert("Please select4");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    if(!vrcyplas())
    {
        alert("Please select5");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    checkAllRecycles;
}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="all">
        <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
                <label >Number of Person Live in Household</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5&nbsp</label>
<br/><br/>
                <label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Energy Consumption Per Month</label>
<br/>
                <label>&nbspElectricity&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <select id="electricity" name='electricity' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="elecuse">0</option>
                <option value="elec1">100</option>
                <option value="elec2">200</option>
                <option value="elec3">300</option>
                <option value="elec4">400</option>
                <option value="elec5">500</option>
                <option value="elec6">600</option>
                <option value="elec7">700</option>
                <option value="elec8">800</option>
                <option value="elec9">900</option>
                </select>
<br/><br/>
                <label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Recycle </label>
<br/>
                <label for='yesalu' class="alu">&nbspAluminium and Steel&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="yesalu" name='yesalu' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<br/>
                <label for='yesplas' class="plas">&nbspPlastic&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="yesplas" name='yesplas' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<br/>
                <button type="button" onclick="checkAllRecycles()">Select All</button>   
<br/>
                <p>Total CO2 produced per year per household:</p>
                <div id="totalConsumption">0</div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="allvalidate()" />
            <input type='reset' id='reset' value='Reset' onclick="hideTotal()" />
        </div>  
       </form>
                    </div>

</body>
```

thx you very much for helping me, stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

hello please check this page :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060313/checking-if-at-least-one-radio-button-has-been-selected-javascript
```